# Search engine for Drupal site, Apache Solr or ElasticSearch?

Tags: 7

Hello Drupal community,

I'm facing a issue for a new site that i'm developping. I need to implement a search engine and don't know which search engine to use between Apache Solr and ElasticSearch. It's the first time I do such work and I am desperatly in need of feedbacks from people who used it in there website and who can tell me the difference it makes in a Drupal site.

Edit : I want a new one to display a search bar in the front office to index all the content of the site in a special way. I also want the results to be displayed right away.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain why you want a new one? what is wrong with the one that is built in? it will help us give you some suggestions.

Comment: @user5482 I edited the question. I hope this guides you a little bit more. Don't hesitate to ask more questions. thanks

Comment: This question is too broad, but even with the necessary details, it would be subjective, and off-topic.

Comment: Did you google "difference apache solr elasticsearch" first? One of the first hits: http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com

Comment: I've seen this site. This one had me lost with all the info. I've seen two site using each one of them and couldn't make a difference in their speed. I wanted to know which one is easier to configure in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache Solr.It has every feature you dream and the searching is super fast.It can search through pdf as well. As per your requirements I suggest to use Apache Solr. It can be easily done with it.